# Apply a media query specific style on click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, refactoring, media-queries

Here's my problem:

I have a menu on the left side. When the screen is too small, the menu takes too much space, so i "minimize" it. 
To do that, I apply a different style when screen width is less than a specific size in pixel. (with media query).

But i would like to allow users to minimize the menu, even on large screen, with a button. Which means to apply the same style as in my media query.

I know I could add a class to the container on a click on the button, and copy/paste the code from the media query for this class, but I suppose there's probably a better way to do it than duplicate the code.

For now:

```
 /* Classic style */
    #menu{
     width:100px;
     background-color:#ddd;
     padding:15px;
    }
    #menu li{
     color:red;
     padding:20px 20px;
    }

 /* Style when screen less than 600px */
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
     #menu{
      width:40px;
      padding:5px;
     }
     #menu li{
      padding: 10px 10px;
     }
     ...
     /* ...a lot more style... $/
    }

 /* Same style when class buttonClicked */
    .buttonClicked #menu{
     width:40px;
     padding:5px;
    }
    .buttonClicked #menu li{
     padding: 10px 10px;
    }
    ...
    /* ...a lot more style... $/
```

This is just a light example, but the style i apply on the menu is much more complex than that, so i would like to avoid duplicate the code if it's possible.

Here's a JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rtnp67s2/3/

**EDIT :** Actually what I'm looking for is to do a **code refactoring** of the style. Is it possible ?

Something like (obviously not working) :

```
 /* Style when screen is less than 600px or when class .buttonClicked active */

    @media (max-width: 600px) OR .buttonClicked {
     #menu{
      width:40px;
      padding:5px;
     }
     #menu li{
      padding: 10px 10px;
     }
     /*... more than 100 lines of styling... */
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't want to add a CSS class try jQuery/javascript. For example, add an 'Increase' button to increase the size and 'Decrease' to decrease size of the menu.
Increase click... $('#menu').css({width:'100px', height: '30px'});
Decrease click... $('#menu').css({width:'90px', height: '20px'});

Comment: I dont mind adding a CSS class, It's just that I would like to apply the minimized style described in the media query on a click without having to repeat it, because this custom style is more than 100 lines of code. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to delete the media query code, and write jQuery script that dynamically adds `.menuMinimized` classes on `click` and `resize` events, or under set value of `$(window).width()`.

However, this could potentially raise new issues in responsive development. If you already have added Bootstrap and jQuery, the bloat of ~100 lines of duplicate code would be insignificant.

Comment: Yes, i would like to avoid using JS. So you don't think there's a way to refactor the code ? (see my edit)

Comment: To my knowledge, something like `@media (max-width: 600px) OR .buttonClicked {` isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can show and hide the menu via button:

```
$("#toggle-menu").click(function(){
    if($('#menu').is(':visible')){
       $("#menu").hide();
    }else{
        $("#menu").show();
    }
})
```